# JavaScript: Ajax Requests in Order

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm writing some JavaScript/AJAX code.

Is there anyway to ensure that the server *receives* the XML requests in the order that they are sent?

If not with plain Ajax, do I get this guarantee if I send everything over a single WebSocket?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need them in order? Why don't you send them one after another then?

Comment: These AJAX requests are fired off by different UI elements. I just need the receiving order to be the same as the sending order.

Comment: Aside on WebSockets, as far as I know they are pretty much just TCP sockets, so yes, order-of-arrival is guarenteed (at least it looks like it)

Comment: Not so. Each ajax request is likely to be a different TCP connection (depending on browser and server implementation). So there's no guarantee that one request will arrive before the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is of utmost importance that they're received in the proper order, and attaching an iterating id to the form isn't enough:

```
msg_number = 1; sendAJAX(msg_number);  msg_number++;
```

Then I'd suggest building your own queue-system, and send each subsequent file as the callback of the previous one.
Rather than each element having its own AJAX-access, create one centralized spot in your application to handle that.

Your different AJAX-enabled sections don't even need to know that it ***is*** a queue:

```
AJAX.send({ url : "......", method : "post", success : func(){}, syncronous : true });
```

On the other side of that, you could have something like:

```
AJAX.send = function (obj) {
    if (obj.synchronous) {
        addToSyncQueue(obj); checkQueue();
    } else { fireRequest(); }
};
```

Inside of your sync queue, all you'd need to do is wrap a new function around the old callback:

```
callback = (function (old_cb) {
    return function (response) {
        checkQueue();
        old_cb(response);
    };
}(obj.success));

obj.success = callback;

AJAX.call(obj);
```

Inside of `checkQueue`, you'd just need to see if it was empty, and if it wasn't, use
`nextObj = queue.shift();` (if you're `.push()`-ing objects onto the queue -- so first-in, first-out, like you wanted).

Answer (score 1):

A couple of options come to mind:

1. Send them synchronously, by waiting for a successful response from the server after each XML request is received (i.e. make a queue).
2. If you know the number of requests you'll be sending beforehand, send the request number as a tag with each request, e.g. `<requestNum>1</requestNum><numRequests>5</numRequests>`.  This doesn't guarantee the order that they're received in, but guarantees that they can be put back in order afterwards, and has the added benefit of being sure that you have all the data.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see your comment about UI elements.  It doesn't sound like option #2 would be the best in this case, so your best bet is to use a queue.  You can roll your own by storing the requests in an array, or use a Javascript framework that has one.  A framework is going to make your Ajax requests a lot easier to handle anyway!

Comment: The second method would still work, unless a single page is going to generate billions of requests, you just keep incrementing the count.

Answer (score 0):

At my company we use this little `ajaxQueue` plugin, written by one of the core jQuery contributors:

http://gnarf.net/2011/06/21/jquery-ajaxqueue/